# Save JSON object in file without rewriting the all file

Tags: c#, json

Heelo everyone,

In my (C#) app, I read JSON objects from files, in order to constructs lists of objects.

My problem is :

when I add object to one of the lists, I want to save this new object into the JSON file without rewriting all the list.

So, do you know if it possible, using JSON from Newtonsoft, to add an object in a JSON file without rewriting all the file. Or should I write myself  a piece of code to do that.

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Actually, I don't have tried anything, I just have searched on the internet (stackoverflow, Newtonsoft documentation) and I haven't find anything about that, or just people who rewrite all the data into the file.